# Android development with Windows XP and no Android device

Tags: android

Hi, I'm planning to learn android app development, but I don't have any Android device. Can I still learn it using my Windows machine?

If so, how to check the output? And can any one suggest me a good tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can develop android application.

You will require....

1. A IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
2. [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) --- This includes an android emulator.

Note:-- Some functionalities are [not supported by android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device) and for that you will require android phone.

Comment: @user737767: see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use windows, and there is a simulator that shows a "virtual" android device thats part of the SDK

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

The Android Guide has everything you need to know to get started.  If you want to test on a real device (and you probably should if at all possible financially), you can either purchase a developer phone from Google or you can buy a cheap (relatively) used one on eBay.

Comment: The "Getting Started Guide" on Google's Android page does include a tutorial and sample app...

Answer (score 0):

you will need Eclipse and SDK for android

http://developer.android.com/index.html from this you will get lots of help

Answer (score 0):

http://www.deviceanywhere.com/Test-Automation

visit the link above. This site lets you test through the web on real devices. It is a paid service though so you might have to decide which one would be cheaper, buying an android 
phone or testing through this site.

Hope this helps.