# Developing android apps without android device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it enough developing android apps without android device (without testing it on a real device not just an emulator)?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what different type of sensors you are willing to use. Emulator is just Android OS however it uses your computer's processor so the results you are getting with your computer's processor will be much more powerful than android device.

If you are willing to monetize your application, it is preferable that you use android device to test your application as you don't want bad user experience do you?

One more point, If you are making application which uses webservices you will get really different results in matter of time to get response from server. As emulator uses your fast broadband internet and your user might be using their 3G network internet, This will make lot of difference.

Conclusion : Depends what type of application you have in your mind. It is preferable to test on device if your application includes internet and lots of sensors.

Just found a really good discussion by professionals, It might help to extend your understanding...

[Android Emulator vs Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device)

Happy Coding!

Comment: thanks. maybe for now i will not use sensors for my app.o better to ask someone to test it for me.

Comment: @nmepntgrm , Check newly added link it has really good discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you would never want to release a professional Android App that you did not try on an actual Android phone. However if you are just making something to give to your friends or for your own use then the simulator is probably good enough.

An option that I did is to buy a used android phone that is not connected to any phone carrier. That way you can buy a dedicated testing device in the $100-200 range with no recurring costs.