# Test on emulator or actual device?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Emulator vs Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device)

Is it better to test your app on an emulator or on an actual Android device? As in to test your app while you are still developing it.

In addition, does testing on the emulator gives you more computing power than actual devices?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device

Comment: Its better to test on real device as in many cases the app works fine on emulator but gives error on a real device

Answer (score 3):

It is always better to test on a real device, as the emulator lacks certain inputs like sensors etc. (especially the older version of it). You will also have problem testing services like In app billing and LVM as the emulator doesn't come with Google Play, and the accounts that can be configured on it are limited.

The best solution is to have a few devices to test on, and use the emulator for testing different screen sizes and how they react to your layouts. There was a Google I/O talk this year that gave you a breakdown of what devices you needed to test on to make sure you have maximum compatibility. I don't remember which one though, sorry.

Comment: Does testing on the emulator gives you more computing power than actual devices?

Comment: Seeing as the emulators emulate an entire ARM processor, you actually end up with a slower environment. However, if you're using one of the x86 images from ICS onwards, then yes, you'll get more power

Comment: What do you mean by "one of the x86 images from ICS"?

Comment: There is an x86 image of the emulator for ICS 4.0.3. That would run faster than any of the ARM emulators, as the processor architecture is the same.

Comment: You can download it via the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the development period,you should test the application on emulator first so that you can test it on multiple targets having different versions eg:2.2, 2.3, 4.0 to find out the loopholes and the resolution issues.
After completion of development you can test it on your actual device for hands on experience.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it certainly depends on your needs. Since you are developing an application that will be consumed not by yourself actually, it will be consumed by your targeted audience and what will they have? They will definitely have real devices to use your application.

There are some features that are not available or really hard to configure on the emulator, like for example you are developing an app that uses a bluetooth feature.

The emulator is certainly designed for developers to test their apps in a virtual environment with limited functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the kind of app you are creating. If you are creating a game that requires the accelerometer then a real device would be beneficial. Yet if you are creating an app with a simple layout and you want to test for different screen dimensions and so on, the emulator is pretty good with this.

Yet you should always have a real device, since the emulator is very limiting.

Answer (score 0):

Android simulator provides a platform very similar to the actual phone, so if your application is running in the simulator, it goes to 94% given the same result in the actual phone, except that sometimes there are modules that must be compulsorily test on a phone like the `GMap`, `Push`, `screen size`..