# Android Emulator vs Real Device [2013]

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is related to question [Android Emulator vs Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device)
What is the current state of art of Android emulators and what are the differences that developers should be aware of. I'm working on an app that uses bluetooth and thinking of adding a feature related to phone calling. Since I can't afford to test on all real devices so what should be the guidelines for developer to test such apps on emulators ?

Answer (score 2):

Genymotion rocks. According to the blog post of Cyril Mottier it is even much better then the hardware devices.

http://www.cyrilmottier.com/2013/06/27/a-productive-android-development-environment/

Comment: Before I sign up, how does their beta work? From their front page: `Easier and more feature-rich, Genymotion will be available in June. Join our community and be among the first to try out the Beta version!`... June of what year?

Comment: The person behind it actually start this on his own as a project. This year a company called Genymotion buy it I think. I don't know what are they planning but the current version is enough actually and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I test basically everything on several real devices. The only thing I use an emulator for is making sure layouts look good on the configurations I don't have available(I don't have a 7" tablet, for instance). This is only after just about everything else is done.

Functionality is going to be *nearly* the same on any real device, and the emulator is no guarantee, since it doesn't seem to act like *any* real device in some cases(openGL, for instance).

Testing usability on a desktop with a mouse just doesn't make sense, unless you're writing something that going to be using that input method. There's a **big** difference between swiping with a finger and click-dragging with a mouse.

Even if you have the fastest emulator/virtualizer in the world, how can it be any faster than just picking up the phone next to you?