# When I press a button and the EditTexts are empty it crashes

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple calculator as my first made by me app and I have two `EditTexts` and if I press any of the 4 calculation buttons the app crashes, I have set a toast message to display if EditText1 & EditText2 are empty and if not do calculation according to button pressed...how can I prevent it from crashing?
Here's my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText number1text;
    EditText number2text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        number1text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1text);
        number2text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2text);
    }

    public void calcadd(View v) { // here
        if (number1text.getText().toString().isEmpty() || number2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else{

        }
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text + num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcminus(View v) { // here 
        if (number1text.getText().toString().isEmpty() || number2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else{

        }
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text - num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcdivide(View v) { // here
        if (number1text.getText().toString().isEmpty() || number2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else{

        }
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text / num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
    }

    public void calcmultiply(View v) { // here
        if (number1text.getText().toString().isEmpty() || number2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else{

        }
        Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
        Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
        Integer ans = num1text * num2text;

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
     }  




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // here
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is my activity_main.xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/num1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" 
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num1text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num1text"
        android:text="@string/num2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/anstxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num2text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num2text"
        android:text="@string/btnadd" 
        android:onClick="calcadd"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/btnminus" 
        android:onClick="calcminus"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="@string/btnmultiply" 
        android:onClick="calcmultiply"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/btndivide" 
        android:onClick="calcdivide"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are calling Integer.parseInt on an empty string. it crashes. don't do that.

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Always.

Comment: I am running it on a phone don't have stracktrace

Comment: @Odie You have all empty else statement. Move your code to do the calculation in those else statements.

Comment: how can i exactly fix that @nzk2 please answer it below

Comment: Test on the emulator, it's better. Test on the phone only sometimes, not by habit.

Comment: well my pc can't handle the emulator

Comment: @njzk2 can you tell me how can i solve that?

Comment: @Tobor, why testing on emulator is better? Users use the apps we write on phones, not emulators. Always test on REAL device by habit (the more devices the better), and additionally on emulator (things like UI on different screens etc.)

Comment: @Melquiades: I don't think so. On an emulator you can **debug**. AND it's **much slower** than a real device, so, if it runs fairly fast on an emulator, it will run even better on a real device. Of course, **the more emulators you test it on, the better**. But you can't buy all the existing phones and tablets...

Comment: @Tobot You're surely entitled to have your own opinion :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device and http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/mobile/mobile-testing-emulators-or-real-devices/

Comment: `I am running it on a phone don't have stracktrace` Yes you do. put the phone in debug mode, and plug it in. Or, run on an emulator. anyway, you can, and you must, post a stacktrace.

Comment: ok thanks for that but it's ok issue resolved by mike yaworski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all four of your if structures where you test for the EditTexts being empty, change this:

```
else{

}
Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
Integer ans = num1text + num2text; // +, -, * or / depending

TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
```

to this (the code needs to be *in* the `else` block):

```
else{
    Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
    Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
    Integer ans = num1text + num2text;

    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
}
```

also, in each of your Toasts, change `getBaseContext()` to `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 8):

```
else{

    }
    Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
    Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
    Integer ans = num1text + num2text;

    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
```

**You do your work outside of the else{} statement, you are checking if they are empty which is good, but then if they are empty " ", you still try to do the calculations by doing them outside of the else brackets.
You should change to what I have shown below...**

```
else{
       Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
       Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
       Integer ans = num1text + num2text;

       TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
       answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());

      }
```

Comment: hold on a sec, I am gonna run it on my emulator and see whats up, because I am having a hard time knowing your problem without a stack trace

Comment: Are you sure you changed the else for all four methods? You need to change calcadd calcminus calcdivide and calcmultiply because all have the content outside of the else

Comment: i changed all of them

Comment: OK, you are going to have to give me a second I am installing the new SDK

Comment: @Odie try changing `getBaseContext()` in all of your Toasts to `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUU @mikeyaworski worked like a charm!

Comment: I just ran your code finally, and it worked fine for me after changing the else statements, my Toasts were left as getBaseContext()... Please consider accepting answer to your resolved question

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is not your current problem

1. Also make sure that you check that you are not dividing by 0 in
   your division function:
       `Integer ans = num1text / num2text;`
2. you can simplify your code creating a function that does the things that are currently
   repeated in every function (DRY; don't repeat yourself)

@1: e.g. by adding another if/else in your division function:

```
    public void calcdivide(View v) { // here
        if (number1text.getText().toString().isEmpty() || number2text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "You Should Put Numbers To Do Calculation",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
        else{
            Integer num1text = Integer.parseInt(number1text.getText().toString());
            Integer num2text = Integer.parseInt(number2text.getText().toString());
            if (num2text>0)
            {
             //only do the division if divisor > 0
             Integer ans = num1text / num2text;
             TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
             answer.setText("Answer:" + ans.toString());
            }
            else
            {
             //e.g. show a toastmessage here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: see above.I've improved my answer